# Math operations in xsl template - XSLTranform geocoordinates from deg to meters

Tags: xml, xslt, math

I haven't been able to make this work. I'm trying to make a template for an xsl tranformation of degrees geocoordinates to meters.
The function in PHP is like this and works just fine:

```
function degtometers($lon, $lat) {
    $half_circumference = 20037508.34;
    $x = round($lon * $half_circumference / 180);
    $y = log(tan((90 + $lat) * pi() / 360)) / (pi() / 180);
    $y = round($y * $half_circumference / 180);
    return 'POINT($x $y)';
}
```

I want to replicate that function in an XSL template. What I have now is this (not working):

```
<xsl:template name="degtometers">
  <xsl:param name="lon"/>
  <xsl:param name="lat"/>
  <xsl:variable name="flon" select="format-number($lon, '#.00000000')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="flat" select="format-number($lat, '#.00000000')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="hcir" select="format-number(20037508.34, '#.00')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="rx" select="format-number($flon * $hcir div 180,'0')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ry" select="format-number(((math:log(math:tan((90 + $flat) * $pi div 360)) div ($pi div 180)) * $hcir div 180),'0')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat( 'POINT(', $rx, ' ', $ry, ')' )"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I have declared the namespace (`xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"`), I've excluded the math prefix (`exclude-result-prefixes="math"`) and tested that math functions work fine but I can't get the template to apply the changes.

I'm calling it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="coordinates" select="normalize-space(mods:subject/mods:cartographics/mods:coordinates)"/>
<xsl:variable name="coolon" select="normalize-space(substring-before($coordinates, ','))"/>
<xsl:variable name="coolat" select="normalize-space(substring-after($coordinates, ','))"/>
<xsl:variable name="coolval">
  <xsl:call-template name="degtometers">
    <xsl:with-param name="lon" select="$coolon"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="lat" select="$coolat"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Any help would be very appreciated, any testing suggestions also would help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is $pi defined?

Comment: Oh! I'm so ashamed... Thank you very much, @kevin-brown!!

Comment: @lalengua, what tools are you using for XSLT development? If you didn't get an error message that pointed you directly to this simple mistake, then you need better development tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested through without the source data, but you missed defining the variable pi. As for testing suggestions, personally I use oXygen for all XSL development. In pasting your template into oXygen, it immediately flagged this problem.

[image]